# How to embed Google Maps in GitHub markdown files

Tags: html, github

I am looking for a way to embed Google Maps in GitHub markdown files. I know that GitHub does not allow the user to use the `<iframe>` tag in .md files, and therefore embedding Google Maps in a .md file might be impossible.

I there any way to use Google Maps in GitHub markdown files?

Comment: Certainly would like an answer to this too. Trying to add a Google Maps page to my Jekyll site is proving frustrating

Answer (score 2):

Go to google maps, search your location, go to 'share' and copy the embed link; paste it into your markdown file and voila!

e.g. try this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d306141.380212437!2d126.3453416664724!3d33.3711157139061!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x350ce3544cc84045%3A0x66bc36d2981ebf31!2sJeju-do%2C+South+Korea!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1473136714592" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please read the question again and show me a working example if `iframe` really works.

Comment: your question wasn't specific enough. looking at your posting history it appears you're trying to do this specifically for the top level README.md file, not as you worded 'GitHub markdown files'.

Comment: I do not understand what history you are talking about. The question title and the question itself are very specific. In addition, your solution does not work even for the top-level `README.md`.